# Pivot on multiple columns and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need to create a T-SQL query that, directly from the SQL Server database, can extract this data, but pivoted by Category.

This is an extract of the query I have now:

[image]

This is the result of the query I would like to obtain:

[image]

I hope someone can help me achieve this. I've been trying for a while, but I can't get exactly what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please avoid posting image. Use formatted text. Please also show you attempted query

Comment: can you add create and insert statements ?

Comment: Is there a maximum to the number of rows per CategoryID? Say, a maximum of 3 rows per category.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192524/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-sql-server